# Merging two datasets using left join in SPSS

Tags: spss

I have two tables. One is called RelationshipFinal and the other MaltPerpFinal2017. I need to merge these two tables using a left join. So basically I want to retain all records from Relationship Final and whichever records in Relationship final that are found in MaltPerpFinal20017 I want to merge them as well. I tried to code it in spss but after the merge I am getting a different number of records. THe number of records should be the same as the RelationshipFinal. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

I tried doing a match files by key variables it didn't work

```
Get file= "C:\Users\gaurelien\WRMA\APS-TARC - Documents\NAMRS DATA Reports\Report Redesign\2018 Structure\Archive\5. Who are the Perpetrators(how is client perp related)\Working folder\Relationship.sav".

sort cases by CaseDataSetID(a) InvestigationId(a) PerpetratorId(a) ClientID(a) StateName (a).
ALTER TYPE StateName(a28).
Save outfile="C:\Users\gaurelien\WRMA\APS-TARC - Documents\NAMRS DATA Reports\Report Redesign\2018 Structure\Archive\5. Who are the Perpetrators(how is client perp related)\Working folder\RelationshipFinal.sav".

Get file= "C:\Users\gaurelien\WRMA\APS-TARC - Documents\NAMRS DATA Reports\Report Redesign\2018 Structure\NAMRS Report Redesign\Exhibits Missing\Working Folder\MaltPerpFinal2017.sav".
sort cases by CaseDataSetID(a) InvestigationId(a)  PerpetratorId(a) ClientID(a) StateName (a).
ALTER TYPE StateName(a28).
save outfile= "C:\Users\gaurelien\WRMA\APS-TARC - Documents\NAMRS DATA Reports\Report Redesign\2018 Structure\Archive\5. Who are the Perpetrators(how is client perp related)\Working folder\MaltPerpFinal2017.sav".

MATCH FILES file="C:\Users\gaurelien\WRMA\APS-TARC - Documents\NAMRS DATA Reports\Report Redesign\2018 Structure\Archive\5. Who are the Perpetrators(how is client perp related)\Working folder\MaltPerpFinal2017.sav" 
      /Table="C:\Users\gaurelien\WRMA\APS-TARC - Documents\NAMRS DATA Reports\Report Redesign\2018 Structure\Archive\5. Who are the Perpetrators(how is client perp related)\Working folder\RelationshipFinal.sav" /by CaseDataSetID
      InvestigationId PerpetratorID ClientID StateName.
Execute.

Save OUTFILE="C:\Users\gaurelien\WRMA\APS-TARC - Documents\NAMRS DATA Reports\Report Redesign\2018 Structure\Archive\5. Who are the Perpetrators(how is client perp related)\Working folder\RelationshipFinal2017.sav".
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you just need to switch what you used for `file` and for `table`. The following is a more efficient version of your code, with the needed correction:

```
cd "C:\Users\gaurelien\WRMA\APS-TARC - Documents\NAMRS DATA Reports\Report Redesign\2018 Structure\Archive\5. Who are the Perpetrators(how is client perp related)\Working folder".

Get file= "Relationship.sav".
sort cases by CaseDataSetID InvestigationId PerpetratorId ClientID StateName .
ALTER TYPE StateName(a28).
Save outfile="RelationshipFinal.sav".

Get file= "C:\Users\gaurelien\WRMA\APS-TARC - Documents\NAMRS DATA Reports\Report Redesign\2018 Structure\NAMRS Report Redesign\Exhibits Missing\Working Folder\MaltPerpFinal2017.sav".
sort cases by CaseDataSetID InvestigationId  PerpetratorId ClientID StateName .
ALTER TYPE StateName(a28).
save outfile= "MaltPerpFinal2017.sav".

MATCH FILES file="RelationshipFinal.sav"
    /Table="MaltPerpFinal2017.sav"/by CaseDataSetID
    InvestigationId PerpetratorID ClientID StateName.
Execute.

Save OUTFILE="RelationshipFinal2017.sav".
```

Note also that you don't need to save the files in order to match them - you can use `dataset name Some_name` for each file you opened, and then use the dataset names in your `match` command instead of file names.

Comment: I am getting an error. Duplicate Key on a Table file. I think I tried that before.  @eli-k

Comment: OK, the problem is you wanted to match cases in `RelationshipFinal` that exist also in `MaltPerpFinal2017`, but if a case in `RelationshipFinal` has more than one match in `MaltPerpFinal2017`, SPSS doesn't know which of them to use... In order to do the match you'll first have to get rid of duplicates, or -  if those matches are not duplicates but have some differences, you can either aggregate them into one row, or else add more fields to match by.